entityManager persist does not persist any data
I am creating a team dashboard with matches from a csv file. I am creating two Entity's - Match and Team. I am using Spring Batch to load matches into postgre and its loading fine. I am able to verify data load complete by querying postgre database. After batch job completion I would like to run some queries to aggregate data for which I am using EntityManager. When I persist from EntityManager I don't see any data in database and don't see any errors. I tried outputing the data stored in hashMap and I see data which I would like to store in database Team table. What could be wrong with the way I am persisting?
import com.project.dashboard.model.Team;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    public JobCompletionNotificationListener(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            log.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results");

            Map<String, Team> teamData = new HashMap<>();

            em.createQuery("select m.team1, count(*) from Match m group by m.team1", Object[].class)
                    .getResultList()
                    .stream()
                    .map(e -> new Team((String) e[0], (long) e[1]))
                    .forEach(team -> teamData.put(team.getTeamName(), team));

            em.createQuery("select m.team2, count(*) from Match m group by m.team2", Object[].class)
                    .getResultList()
                    .forEach(e -> {
                        Team team = teamData.get((String) e[0]);
                        team.setTotalMatches(team.getTotalMatches() + (long) e[1]);
                    });

           em.createQuery("select m.winner, count(*) from Match m group by m.winner", Object[].class)
                   .getResultList()
                   .forEach(e -> {
                       Team team = teamData.get((String) e[0]);
                       if(team!=null)
                       {
                           team.setTotalWins((team.getTotalWins() + (long) e[1]));
                       }
                    });

           teamData.values().forEach(em::persist);
           teamData.values().forEach(System.out::println);
        }

    }
}


Sounds like the transaction for the insertion is independent of the transaction for the query and the former has not committed when the latter is executed.  Not sure how test that hypothesis or how to resolve it in your specific case.

It seems like it's already a transaction context, maybe what is missing is flush.
teamData.values().forEach(em::persist);
em.flush(); // Ensure the persistence context is synchronized with the database
teamData.values().forEach(System.out::println);


I get an error jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
